# How to add space into a string

Tags: c++

In HTML, you basically add   "&nbsp" and so it will create a blank space but I dont know how to do it in c++
code:

```
string word = "";
cout << "give a word:";
cin >> word; 
cout << "your word is" << word<<"";
```

Result:

> give a word: Car
>
> your word isCar (no space between "is" and "Car")

While I want it to be like:

> give a word: Car
>
> your word is Car (there's a space now between "is" and "Car")

Comment: Just change the "your word is" to "your word is " (note the space on the end).  It's a string literal, you don't need any special coding for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a space after "is":

```
"your word is " <<
```

This is the kind of thing you probably could have figured out if you sat there and thought about it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "your word is " << word;
```

Add a space " " in your constant string.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cout << "your word is" << word<<"";
```

to:

```
cout << "your word is " << word<<"";
//                 ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Ading a space in C++ is not so hard because it is a string literal. To answer your question, the simplest way to add a space in your output is to modify the cout statement iteslf by adding a space where you rquire it to be. In your case, it would be like: (also added some more tips)

```
string word; // unrequired to define word as blank here; you will take it as input later
cout << "give a word: "; // Added a space after "word"
cin >> word; 
cout << "Your word is " << word << endl; // you do not need "" because that outputs nothing. If you want to print a new line, use "endl" or "\n".
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a space between variables:

```
string name = "jauda";
string surname = "blabla";

cout << name << " " << surname;
```